# Linux file permissions and file_exists puzzle

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

I have following file structure under my project

```
upload-cv
  -> cvs
    -> {date}
      -> {token}{filename}
```

Permissions of these folders are following:

```
drwxr-xr-x gjm psaserv upload-your-cv/
drwxrwxrwx gjm psaserv cvs

drwxrwxrwx 2 apache apache 2012-07-01
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache e63b64d3e222af1ec0d18f51c9f378f0SURINDER SINGH (2).doc
```

`apache` user is a member of `psaserv` group.

Problem is that when I check in PHP with `file_exists` function if file *e63b64d3e222af1ec0d18f51c9f378f0SURINDER SINGH (2).doc* exists, it returns FALSE. If I change owner of that file to `gjm:psaserv` it returns TRUE.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: How do you run your php code ? From within the server or from the command line ?

Comment: from server, user that runs that script is "apache"

Answer (score 0):

If your server runs with group `psaserv`, your "htdocs" should get that group. It should also work, to have the user as `apache` and the group as `psaserv`.